# externally constant variable

Tags: c, variables, constants

I have a variable defined in one of my files, It may be manipulated by the code in the file itself, but it is always a constant value to any external file.

How do i declare the variable as constant without raising errors on assigning this variable a value inside the file it is defined in while allowing compiler to optimize it's read as if it is a constant in those external units ?

Comment: A variable that you can modify is not constant...

Comment: It's a peice of kernel code, "current_thread" to be specific, it is ALWAYS constant when being read by code external to my threading code (which is ensured because currently it is UP only).

Comment: Don't make the variable externally available. Instead provide a function that returns its value. This prevents any other code from modifying it while permitting the code in same module to change it.

Comment: Declare a separate variable which is const and stores the value of the extern variable

Comment: @PeterGluck, the quote from const tag, "Const is a qualifier used to define a data storage area (object, field, variable, parameter) that "never changes", thus allowing extra code generator optimizations and additional static checking of program correctness."

Comment: Frankly I think you are worrying about nothing - any "optimizations" are unlikely to make any difference to you here. Simply use the clearest way of exposing the value to the user - think `pthread_self()`...

Comment: @Nim, i am not using pthread.. it's an embedded kernel and i can already see the compiler reloading the values and spilling the registers on stack because it reloads the value of current_thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rvalue can't be modified. Use an accessor function to access it guarantees you only offer an rvalue, e.g.

```
static int value;

extern int getconst();

int getconst() {
  return value;
}
```

This makes:

```
getconst() = -1; // Compiler error
```

Alternatively you can expose your value via a `const` pointer to a `const int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int value = -1;

extern const int * const public_non_modifiable;
const int * const public_non_modifiable = &value;


int main() {
  printf("%d\n", *public_non_modifiable); // fine
  *public_non_modifiable = 0; // compiler error
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring in the file that modifies the virables as follows:

```
int e = 0, e_ant = 0, adj;
```

and declaring in the other files in this way:

```
extern const int e, e_ant, adj;
```

works for me. I am using a dsPIC with MPLAB.

The first file computes the value of all the variables. A second file only shows those values in a LCD Display, with a totally forbiden writing of this variables.